# Why do & behave differently for strings?

Tags: c++, string, char

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

    char x[100]="hello";

    int s=strlen(x);

    cout<<&(x[0]);

}
```

If I compile and run it,

the output is hello

Why isn't the output the address of the charecter 'h' ?

Comment: try `cout<<(void*)&(x[0]);`

Comment: This has been answered so many times

Comment: "Why isn't the output the address of the charecter 'h' ?" – it is, you just have to interpret it appropriately.

Comment: @texasbruce 
I tried searching for a similar question.
But It isn't that easy to search a question like this
I regret the inconvenience thus caused.

Answer (score 10):

Because the `operator <<` is overloaded for `const char*` to print the zero-terminated C-string pointed to by the `const char*`.

Comment: Which leads to hilarious results if you actually were trying to print the address and the char* does not actually point to a zero terminated array of chars.

Comment: @Cubic A simple cast ro `void*` serves well, if you want the address.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers do not keep the information whether they point to a single object or the first object of an array. Also take into account that array names in expressions are converted to pointers to their first elements. So if you have for example a pointer of type `const char *` like this

```
const char *p = "Hello";
```

then it is naturally to expect that this statement

```
std::cout << p << std::endl;
```

will output string literal "Hello".

If you want to output the address of the first element of the string literal you have to use another overloaded `operator <<` for pointers of type `void *`

```
std::cout << ( const void * )p << std::endl;
```

So there is a dilemma how to process pointers of type `char *` and it was resolved in favor to consider such pointers as pointers to first elements of character strings and consequently to output the whole string.

Comment: May I ask why you keep rolling back perfectly valid edits that improve the formatting of your own answer?

Comment: @Jefffrey  Yes, you may ask.:) I did not roll back edits. It seems that we were editing simultaneously and when I was saving my edits your edits had been discarded.:)